# Failed to get property of non-object

Tags: php

i have a problemm with extracting data from database, it inserts it correctly but it wont display it.

This is the function for it from controller:

```
$post = $this->postModel->getPostById($id);

$user = $this->userModel->getUserById($post->user_id);

$data = [
    'post' => $post,
    'user' => $user
];

$this->view('posts/show', $data);
```

And this is function from database:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id');

$this->db->bind(':id', $id);

$row = $this->db->single();

return $row;
```

This is the HTML for one line that i get error for:
`echo $data['post']->title`

Comment: you should be really using null checks

Answer (score 0):

You have a record that has a null value on 'title' field.

Comment: this can be a comment

Comment: i solved it, aprently the controller was not unset so it took wrong value from URL, thank you